# "ZeroDivisionError" troubleshooting

Tags: python

I'm currently beginning an "intro to programming" class using python and I am trying to find the quotient and remainder of a supposedly simple math equation, where the user inputs any 2 positive numbers and my program finds the quotient and remainder. My problem is whenever I think I've completed it correctly, It gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./prog.py", line 3, in <module>
    quotient = (dividend/divisor)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

My code:

```
divisor = int(input("Enter a Divisor: "))
dividend = int(input("Enter a Dividend: "))
quotient = (dividend/divisor)
reminder = (dividend % divisor)
print("Quotient is", quotient)
print("Reminder is", reminder)
```

Comment: Please edit your code into the question itself rather than linking to a screenshot of it. - Same with the error.

Comment: sorry, just created this account and totally new to stack overflow, I'll work on that in the future

Comment: If you input 0 as denominator, it gives this error. What would you expect any other than this?

Comment: dude I'm entirely new to programming, you're einstein in comparison to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user gives a value for `divisor` that is `0`, then the line `quotient = (dividend/divisor)` will try to divide whatever `dividend` is by `0`. In terms of arithmetic, this doesn't mean anything at all (it can't be done). See [this for details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero).

Of course, Python is right to give you an error. **But it doesn't mean that anything is wrong with your code, really, simply that the user has asked for something impossible, and given invalid input.**

If you want to handle this invalid input, you can either explicitly check that the divisor is not zero, e.g.:

```
divisor = int(input("Enter a Divisor: "))

if divisor == 0:
    print("Nope, bye.")
else:
    dividend = int(input("Enter a Dividend: "))
    quotient = (dividend/divisor)
    reminder = (dividend % divisor)
    print("Quotient is", quotient)
    print("Reminder is", reminder)
```

Or you can use a `try except` block to catch the exception and do something else, e.g.:

```
divisor = int(input("Enter a Divisor: "))
dividend = int(input("Enter a Dividend: "))

try:
    quotient = (dividend/divisor)
    reminder = (dividend % divisor)
    print("Quotient is", quotient)
    print("Reminder is", reminder)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Something else")
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching a noob, needed this explanation

Answer (score 0):

try first to have your input entered and then turning it into an integer.

also, check whether the devisor is 0 or not